Disable pointer compression in Electron rendering process
When I created a large number of SVG elements and JS objects during the rendering process, it caused an OOM error. I found a way to recompile the electron source code by disabling V8 pointer compression, but it didn't work.
This is my attempt. Added some parameters:
v8\BUILD.gn
v8_enable_pointer_compression = false
v8_enable_pointer_compression_shared_cage = false

electron\build\args\all.gn
v8_enable_pointer_compression = false
v8_enable_pointer_compression_shared_cage = false

Then I compiled the Electron v20-x-y source code
But the memory size of the rendering process still hasn't changed
> performance.memory.jsHeapSizeLimit / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 + 'GB'
3.5 GB

I have tried many methods, but none of them have been effective

Have you tried setting a larger max heap size (in addition to disabling pointer compression)?
